# Use built-in "Follow" action with a custom object type

Tags: facebook-opengraph, custom-object

How can I achieve such a thing?  I have a custom object type - for example, a `Club`. I want users of my app to be able to `Follow` a `Club`, which has a manager that posts general club updates, etc.  The two approaches I can come up with are:

A - Change my custom `Club` object type to use the built-in `Profile` object type.

B - Choose a synonym for `Follow` and try to get a custom action through the review process.

I already tried submitting as a custom `Subscribe` action and was rejected. Option A seems like I would be using the system against the way that it was designed to be used.

**Clarification**

I don't care about the user receiving facebook notifications or "following" the club in the facebook sense of the word.  I just want to publish something to the user's timeline such as "Sammy followed a club on MyApp."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook allows you to have a custom "Follow" action, but they don't make it obvious... for obvious reasons.

1. Create a custom action with a name *other than* `follow`
2. On the next page, change the name to `follow`

This is not sneaky in any way. After being rejected several times for synonymous actions like "track" and "subscribe" to try to work around the implied no-custom-follows limitation, it was finally **suggested to me by the reviewer** that I use the word "follow" for my custom action.